# LUIS in Austria

Tags: azure, azure-language-understanding, azure-cognitive-services

I was asking if I could use LUIS in Austria (Central Europe). The pricing section for Europe is segmented in West and North Europe. Is it possible to get a pricing for West Europe and use the Service in Austria? And if yes, is it recommended to do so?

LUIS Pricing:
https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/cognitive-services/

PS: I know it's not a coding question, but this is one of the best forums to ask this question.

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to ask their Sales team about this?